# Can I link to Google Maps with the 'LatLng Marker' enabled?

Tags: google-maps

Rather than explaining to my students how to enable the 'LatLng Marker' (Settings --> Maps Labs --> Enable LatLng Marker), I would like to just give them a link with the marker enabled. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you want to show a map to the students with markers set by you or do you want your students to set their own marker without having to enable LatLng Marker in Labs?

Comment: I want students to be able to look use google maps with this tool enabled so that they can find a place and report the lat/long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this. Because the page uses AJAX you can not just use the URL of the *Save Changes* button from *Google Maps Labs* like in the old days.
Your best bet would be to tell your students to log in to their Google account and change the setting once. The setting would be saved for the following sessions.